# Select multiple field using select

Tags: node.js, mongoose, select, filter, limit

I am requesting using postman
this is url

**http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tours?fields=name,price**

```
if(req.query.fields){
        let fields=req.query.fields.split(',').join(" ");
        console.log(fields);
        query=query.select(fields);
    }
    else{
        query=query.select('-__v');
    }
```

I aspect that output is only name and price fields of tours collection, but i had got no  result

please help me to resolve this promlem

But When I same for **sort** method working perfectly
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tours?sort=price,averageRating

```
if(req.query.sort){
    let sortBy=req.query.sort.split(',').join(" ");
    query=query.sort(sortBy);
}

else{

    query=query.sort('-createdAt');
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine.
What result are you getting? What are you expecting? Is anything else different in the code between the two scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In the code, where you declare the excluded fields, I had a typo in the array :

```
const excludeFields = ['page', 'sort', 'limit', 'fields'];
```

I misspelled `fields` (it was `fileds` instead)